# Different Callback for each subplot using subplot2grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, callback, subplot

Hello dear Python comunity developper,
I would like to know if there is a way to have **different callback for every subplot2grid (matplotlib),**
**For example:** For the first subplot2grid I want to execute a function which is different from the second subplot2grid that generates executes another function.

I specify that i'm using subplot2grid and not subplot in matplotlib.
Thank you,

Comment: You maybe could wrap your function and then count the number of time you already execute the function. With that information, you could call another callback ?

Comment: Thnx for answer,
Do you have an example please?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but you could probably do it in two steps: the callback function figures out from with Axe (subplot) the event was generated, and based on that, call a second function, different for each of the subplots. It all depends on what kind of Event you are interested in processing

Comment: @DizietAsahi I'm defining a new Callback function in each subplot2grid, But it doesn't work :-(
Is is possible to include a button beside each subplot, without using Tk()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to use a `widget.Button` for each subplot, then the situation is very easy. To create a button you need to pass it an `Axes` instance and the button will occupy that space. So you need to create as many new axes as you have subplots, and specify their coordinates appropriately. Then create your buttons, which can have different callback functions.

for example:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def callback1(event):
    print "you've clicked button 1"

def callback2(event):
    print "you've clicked button 2"

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(0, 0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2),(1,1))

# create axes to receive the buttons
# adjust the coordinates to suit your needs
# coordinates are [left, bottom, width, height]
b1ax = plt.axes([0.5, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1])
b1 = Button(b1ax, 'Button 1')
b1.on_clicked(callback1)
b2ax = plt.axes([0.7, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1])
b2 = Button(b2ax, 'Button 2')
b2.on_clicked(callback2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

documentation for `widget.Button`: http://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Button

example of implementation: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/buttons.html

Comment: Ah thnx a lot, that's what I was looking for,
Another question ^^ : Is there a way to set other parameters with event parameter in the called function.
^^

Comment: I found the solution for my last question:


b2ax_outgoing = plt.axes([0.4, 0.4, 0.01, 0.02])
bouttonni2 = buttonn(b2ax_outgoing, '', color='red')
bouttonni2.on_clicked(lambda event: taux_outgoing2(reader, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, tech, event))

THNX A LOT

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful to you, consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark on the left